# ¿Qué función tiene el operador & en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando descifrar un código que me han pasado.

En una de las operaciones del código tenemos la siguiente operación:

```
A = B & C
```

Cuando imprimo A, B y C:

```
print (A)
print (B)
print (C)
```

Obtengo como output algo parecido a lo siguiente (las cadenas de caracteres están inventadas):

```
frozenset({('234', 'bla bla bla'),('8', 'blo blo blo'),('1','oe oe')})
frozenset({('2', 'bla'),('9', 'blo'),('11','oe')})
frozenset({('23', 'ddd'),('3', 'brr'),('44','e')})
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Qué función tiene el signo & en la operación? ¿Qué hace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En el contexto en el que se usa en tu caso el operador `&` realiza la operación matemática conocida como **intersección de conjuntos**.

Un conjunto o [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) es una colección de objetos sin repetición y desordenados. Se implementan mediante tablas hash por lo que los objetos deben ser "hashables" como ocurre con `str`, `tuple`, `frozenset`, `int` o `float` (objetos mutables como los conjuntos en si mismos o las listas no son permitidos como elementos de un conjunto al no ser "hashables"). Dentro de sus ventajas están una gran eficiencia en búsquedas o la posibilidad de hacer operaciones como la intersección (`A & B`), union(`A | B`), diferencia(`A - B`) o la diferencia simétrica(`A ^ B`).

Si tenemos dos conjuntos `A` y `B`, `A & B` nos **retorna otro conjunto que solo contiene los elementos que están presentes en ambos a la vez**, descartando aquellos que estén presentes solo en uno:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es equivalente a usar el método [`set.intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection).

```
>>> A = {1, 2, 5, 7}
>>> B = {4, 5, 1, 9}
>>> C = {2, 5, 7}
>>> A & B
{1, 5}
>>> A & B & C
{5}

>>> A.intersection(B)
{1, 5}
```

Funciona de forma idéntica para [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) que no es más que un conjunto inmutable (y que si puede ser un elemento de otro `set` o `frozenset` al ser "hashable"):

```
>>> A = frozenset((("A", 1), ("A", 2), ("B", 4)))
>>> B = frozenset((("B", 4), ("B", 2), ("A", 2)))
>>> A & B
frozenset({('A', 2), ('B', 4)})
```

Como se puede ver el conjunto retornado solo incluye aquellos elementos (en este caso tuplas)  que están presentes tanto en `A` como en `B` al mismo tiempo.

---

En otros contextos , por ejemplo aplicado a enteros, es un operador a nivel de bit, el and binario (bitwise and). Retornará, por cada bit de la salida, 1 si ambos bits son 1 y 0 en caso contrario:

```
>>> 58 & 43
42

>>> bin(58)
'0b111010'
>>> bin(43)
'0b101011'
>>> bin(42)
'0b101010'
```

Como se puede ver, toma cada pareja de bits de los operandos y solo retorna 1 si ambos bits son también 1:

```
1 1 1 0 1 0     # 58
& & & & & &     
1 0 1 0 1 1     # 43
⇓ ⇓ ⇓ ⇓ ⇓ ⇓    
1 0 1 0 1 0     # 42
```

> Se puede sobrecargar el operador `&` para que pueda ser usado con
>   cualquier objeto. Para ello se definen los métodos [`__and__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) y
>   `__rand__` en la clase, que serán los encargados de retornar el resultado apropiado
>   al aplicar el operador sobre las isntancias de esa clase. Esto nos permite crear
>   objetos propios que puedan ser operandos de `&` como lo es la clase
>   `set`.